# Sql insert using C# - Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: c#, sql

Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition. I'm not sure why.

```
public void saveToDB()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString);
    con.Open();
    string cmdtext = "Insert into tbl_user values ('" + txtname.Text + "','" + txtemail.Text + "','" + txtPassword.Text + "')";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdtext, con);
    int no = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (no > 0)
    {
        SendEmail();
        Response.Write("Register Succesfully");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("Epic FAILED");
    }
}
```

My database has:

- name(varchar)
- email(varchar)
- password(varchar)
- activated(bit)

Comment: First thing to do: stop building SQL like that. Use parameterized SQL, every time.

Comment: 1) you are not supplying values for all of the columns (just 3 of the 4), 2) switch to use parameters instead.  It prevents several _other_ problems.

Comment: Everyone is pointing out the lack of parameterized query but ignoring the PLAIN TEXT PASSWORD being stored in the database

Answer (score -1):

For insert statements, if you dont insert into all the columns, (except Identity columns), you need to specify the column names, like so

```
 string cmdtext = "Insert into tbl_user(name, email, password) values ('" + txtname.Text + "','" + txtemail.Text + "','" + txtPassword.Text + "')";
```

As per the comments, I neglected to let you know about best practices with SQL: check out [how to prevent SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/csharp).

Comment: While this is technically correct, it's unhelpful in that it's leaving the *massive* SQL injection vulnerability wide open. Addressing that should always be the primary concern, IMO... better to have code that fails to do anything than code that works sometimes but leaves a security vulnerability.